# Left side of website is lowered

Tags: html

The right and middle side of my website look normal, but the left side is dropped down. Can someone help me fix this? Please full screen the code snipplet. The box is so small it crams it all together. If anyone has a fix or a suggestion then tell me. My website is pure html btw. Note you might see some audio errors. On my actual website i have music and stuff.

```html
<html>
<!-- WEBSITE -->
<title> Auron's website </title>

<style>
  #container {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  #center {
    margin: auto;
  }
  /* Remaining CSS is identical to original */
  
  #p12 {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    animation: typing 1.3s steps(20, end), blink-caret .75s steps(50, end) infinite;
  }
  
  #p12 {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  /* The typing effect */
  
  @keyframes typing {
    from {
      width: 0
    }
    to {
      width: 100%
    }
  }
  /* The typewriter cursor effect */
  
  @keyframes blink-caret {
    from,
    to {
      border-color: transparent
    }
    50% {
      border-color: orange;
    }
  }
  
  audio {
    display: none;
  }
  
  hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid darkred;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .test {
    width: 11em;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
  }
</style>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<body style="background-color:silver;">


  <audio controls volume="0.6" preload="auto" autoplay id="audio1" loop>
            <source src="kde.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
         Your browser does not support this audio file.
        </audio>

  <span style="float:right;"> 
        <head>
<!-- INSERT JQUERY -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    var ampm = h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  h = h % 12;
  h = h ? h : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById("txt").style.color = "darkred";
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + ampm;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

var myAudio = document.getElementById("audio1");

function playPause() { 
    if (myAudio.paused) 
        myAudio.play(); 
    else 
        myAudio.pause(); 
} 
</script>
            

<!-- JQUERY CODE -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        $("#test").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
</script>

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-1488256319567534",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
</script>                        
            
</head>
        <body onload="startTime()">
<div id="txt"></div>
        </span>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="center">
      <p id="p12" style="color:red;font-size:20px">
        <b>Welcome to my website!</b>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <center>
    <p style="color:blue">Hello, This my website. If you look at the code it's all wacky! Probably because i'm to lasy to organize it. Or just because i'm happy it works. Anyway, at-least the code runs correctly! Just so you know this was run on chrome. So if the website has
      random code on screen then that means it doesn't support your browser. Well, Bye! </p>
  </center>
  <!-- BORDER -->
  <hr color:darkred>
  <!-- BORDER -->
  <!-- COLOR FOR TEXT DO NOT CHANGE -->
  <span style="color:darkred">
    <P align=right style="margin-right: 140px;" class="update" id="hide"> Update List: </P> 

        <!-- UPDATE LIST -->
<span> <ul style="margin-right: 10px;" class="update test" id="hide">
    <li> 1.0 Website released! </li>
    <li> 1.1 Click copyright to hide. </li>
    <li> 1.2 Welcome sound added. </li>
    <li> 1.3 24 hour clock is now
         a 12 hour clock. </li>
    <li> 1.4 Website music! </li>
    <li> 1.5 Added pause/play button. </li>
    <li> 1.6 Ads </li>
    <li> 1.7 Added some animation!</li>
    </ul> </span>


  <!-- ACTUAL TEXT! -->
  <p align="center">
    If you find a bug or have a suggestion, click here: </p>
  <p align=middle> <a href=captcha.html>Email Link</a>
  </p>

  <!-- MAIN TEXT -->

  <i> I use KDE Neon
    <a href="https://neon.kde.org/">for my OS. </a> </i>
  <p> Click the link if you want to try it out! </p>

  <p>
    My Desktop is a <b>Custom Dell Inspiron 3656</b> SPECS:
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>CPU: AMD A10-8700P 1.8 GHZ 4-core</li>
    <li>RAM: 12 GB DDR3</li>
    <li>HDD: 930 GB</li>
    <li>OS: Windows 10 Professional 64-bit</li>
    <li>SCREEN: 1920 X 1080</li>
  </ul>
  <p> Donate to KDE Neon or ReactOS! </p>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="https://www.reactos.org/donating">ReactOS </a> </li>

    <li> <a href="https://www.kde.org/community/donations/">KDE Neon </a> </li>
  </ul>

  <p> Wanna try the OS before installing it? Try <a href="https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads">VirtualBox! </a> </p>
  <p> My Youtube and Twitch channels!
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMF9lXrFi9k4A1EHRKc3-fw">Youtube </a> </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.twitch.tv/mrmajik45">Twitch </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- COPYRIGHT -->
    <p style="font-size:12px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:100%; text-align: center" id="test"> Auron's website © </p>


    <button style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;" onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>

    <form style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: auto; right: 0; top: auto" action="calc.html">
      <input type="submit" value="Calculator" />
    </form>
    <!-- END OF CODE -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are a lot errors in this html. Not worth trying to do anything with it. You are better of redoing it.

Comment: @Dejan.S Are you sure? I just fixed it using flex.

Comment: I'm sure. I don't have time this very second but I can show you how it can be done. I'll do so later today

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge mess. It's because you aren't defining any widths or floating that section to the left. If you want something all the way to the left without anything interfering with it, you would want to put that first in your code and make it float left with a defined width.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to devide the different sections. This is a very basic example but that would work for your situation. You can now place the content inside the `.main__[position]` areas. I haven't made any breakpoints, that's up to you how you like them. You can rename the classnames if you don't like that approach (BEM).

```css
body {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.header {
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main__left {
  flex-basis: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.main__middle {
  flex-basis: 2;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: white;
}

.main__right {
  flex-basis: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.footer {
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  My header
</header>

<main class="main">
  <div class="main__left">left</div>
  <div class="main__middle">middle</div>
  <div class="main__right">right</div>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
  My footer
</footer>
```